# Get an object result from an activity in Xamarin with Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-activity, xamarin, onactivityresult

I want to receive an object back from a child activity in Xamarin with Visual Studio 2015:

```
[Serializable]
class MyObj
{
    public string value { get; }

    public MyObj(string v)
    {
        value = v;
    }
}
```

**Child Activity**

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent (this, typeof(FirstActivity));
MyObj obj = new MyObj("message");
myIntent.PutExtra ("obj", obj);                                        // cannot convert "obj" to Bundle
SetResult (Result.Ok, myIntent);
Finish();
```

**FirstActivity**

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0)
        if (resultCode == Result.Ok) {
            var helloLabel = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.helloLabel);
            MyObj obj = data.GetSerializableExtra("obj") as MyObj;
            helloLabel.Text = obj.Text.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

This code causes an error `cannot convert obj to Bundle`. I've also tried to implement `Java.IO.ISerializable is MyObj` but I couldn't get a right implementation. It always throws `System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type MyApp.MyObj from native handle 0x10001d (key_handle 0x1a027cb)`

```
class Object1 : Java.Lang.Object, Java.IO.ISerializable
{
    public string value { get; }
    public Object1(string v)
    {
        value = v;
    }
}
```

I would like to get some advice. I'm new in Xamarin and I'm working with Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 1):

I'd always go for `Parcelable`. It's very fast! (**10x faster**) http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/

Here is how you implement it in Xamarin:

```
public class MyObj : Java.Lang.Object, IParcelable
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public MyObj()
    {
    }

    private MyObj(Parcel parcel)
    {
        // read your values in order
        Value = parcel.ReadString();
    }

    public void WriteToParcel(Parcel dest, ParcelableWriteFlags flags)
    {
        // read your values in order
        dest.WriteString(Value);
    }

    // -- stuff below here is needed from the parcel interfaces/mechanism --

    [ExportField("CREATOR")]
    public static MyObjCreator InitializeCreator()
    {
        return new MyObjCreator();
    }

    public class MyObjCreator : Java.Lang.Object, IParcelableCreator
    {
        public Java.Lang.Object CreateFromParcel(Parcel source)
        {
            return new MyObj(source);
        }

        public Java.Lang.Object[] NewArray(int size)
        {
            return new MyObj[size];
        }
    }

    public int DescribeContents()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**SetResult**

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(FirstActivity));
MyObj obj = new MyObj {Value = "Hello"};
myIntent.PutExtra("obj", obj);
SetResult(Result.Ok, myIntent);
Finish();
```

**OnActivityResult**

```
var x = (MyObj)data.GetParcelableExtra("obj");
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing complex objects is a bit tricky. You can use libraries like [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to serialize to string before sending,  and then deserialize on the other end.

```
myIntent.PutExtra ("obj", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
```

//in your receiving activity `OnActivityResult`...

```
var objectAsString = intent.GetStringExtra("obj")
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(objectAsString)
```

Nice and easy solution and well performing too..

Comment: How can I get the object back?